# Change permissions for gcc and g++ in Windows

Tags: gcc, cygwin

I have installed all packages in cygwin. I have also added C:\cygwin\bin to my PATH variable. But when I try to compile a c++ file in command line I get the error 'Access is denied'. The same commands work in the cygwin batch window.

I have 64-bit version of Windows, and have installed all the necessary packages of cygwin.

Update: The .exe file is being made. I can run it directly.

Comment: From which directory are your trying to compile? Also please post the whole command and error you're getting.

Comment: Tried running it on both C:\ and D:\. Same result on both occasions.

Answer (score 3):

`/bin/gcc` in Cygwin is a symbolic link to either `gcc-3` or `gcc-4`. Similarly for `g++`. Non-Cygwin programs can't usually read Cygwin symbolic links, which is why running gcc works in a Cygwin bash but not in the Windows command prompt (i.e. cmd.exe). Hence you need to invoke `gcc-3` or `gcc-4` directly from there.

(The somewhat misleading "Access is denied" message occurs because Cygwin symbolic links are represented by files with the system attribute set, but they're nevertheless readable by anyone.)

Answer (score 1):

That's expected behavior: Cygwin provides a POSIX-like environment on top of Windows, it needs some setup (the Cygwin Bash window).

If you want native Windows GCC, you need [MinGW(-w64)](http://mingw-w64.sourceforge.net/). They function without Cygwin, and target the Win32 API (msvcrt.dll).

Comment: I tried using MinGW before this. Not the -w64 version though. How do I use the snapshot of MinGW (-w64)?

Comment: Read [here](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/mingw-w64/wiki/Downloading%20and%20installing%20MinGW-w64) Your best bet is to use my or sezero's Personal Builds.